# DataTables warning: Requested unknown parameter "FileName"... using Json

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a view which loads the script:

```
var dataTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});

function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#DT_load').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/musicfiles/getall/",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            {
                "data": "albumartpath",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `<img src="~/images/" + ${data} ?? "noimage.webp" asp-append-version="true" height="50" width="50" />`;
                }, "width": "20%"
            },
            { "data": "filename", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "title", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "artist", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "genre", "width": "20" }
        ],
        "language": {
            "emptyTable": "no data found"
        },
        "width": "100%"
    });
}
```

and a MusicFilesController function which returns a Json:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
{
    JsonResult json = Json(new { data = await _context.MusicFiles.ToListAsync() });
    return json;
}
```

but when I load the page, I get the error:

> DataTables warning: table id=DT_load - Requested unknown parameter 'FileName' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

The Json is correctly formatted using strings but I cannot figure out what I am missing. I have looked through about a dozen other posts with similar issues but have not found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Requested unknown parameter 'FileName' for row 0, column 1.

In your code, we can find that you specify `columns.data` option with `{ "data": "filename", "width": "20%" }`, if the data source object item(s) with key **`fileName`** like below (not `filename` you specified), which would cause the issue.

```
{"albumartpath":"https://xxxx/xxx","fileName":"xxx","title":"xxx","artist":"xxx","genre":"xx"}
```

So please double check the received data on client side and make sure you set the data source for the column correctly.